# LDAP Authentication Error for LoginDN - CN=Administrator,OU=Users,DC=gms,DC=admin,DC=com

Tags: ldap

LoginDN is CN=Administrator,OU=Users,DC=gms,DC=admin,DC=com
It throws javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C09042F, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v2580

Comment: Where is your code ?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I think you put the wrong password.

For more information, [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/stashkb/ldap-error-code-49-317195698.html)